# Display unobtrusive validation message in two lines using <br/> tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am working on an asp.net MVC3 application there I am using Unobtrusive validation.
In that i have a Error Message which I wanr to show in two lines , the Error message I am defining as:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your password must be at least 6 characters long. <br/> Please try again.")]
```

I want to encode the break tag in validation message, and want to show the message in two lines.
I have tried following thing:

1.)

```
@{
string s = Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password).ToString();
}
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s))
```

2.)

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password).ToString()))
```

3.)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your password must be at least 6 characters long. //n Please try again.")]
```

None of the above is working.

Can any one help??

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

Put the validation message inside a div of fixed width and the message text should wrap onto the next line.